# Essential subgroups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

How can I show that E is essential in an abelian group A if and only if it contains the socle of A and A/E is torsion?

I know that a subgroup E of an abelian group A is **essential** if its intersection with any non-zero subgroup of A is non-zero and that the **socle** of A is the set of all the elements whose order is a square-free integer.

Thank you!!!

Comment: 1. Show an essential subgroup contains every element of prime order and a nontrivial multiple of every element of infinite order. 2. Use the fact that $A/E$ is torsion to conclude it intersects any subgroup with elements of infinite order, and that it contains the socle to show it intersects nontrivially every other subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be an abelian group with socle $B$.

For the forward direction, assume $E$ is an essential subgroup of $A$.

We want to show $A/E$ is torsion and $B\subseteq A$.

Let $a\in A$ with $a\ne 0$.

Then $E\cap \langle{a}\rangle\ne 0$, hence $na\in E$ for some nonzero integer $n$.

It follows that $a$ has finite order, mod $E$.

Since this holds for all nonzero $a\in A$, it follows that $A/E$ is torsion.

Next let $b\in B$ with $b\ne 0$.

Since the order of $b$ is squarefree, it follows that $\langle{b}\rangle$ is the internal direct sum of finitely many cyclic subgroups, $C_1,...,C_k$ say, each of prime order.

Since a cyclic group of prime order has no nonzero subgroups other than itself, $E$ must contain each of $C_1,...,C_k$.

It follows that $\langle{b}\rangle\subseteq E$, hence $b\in E$.

Since we also have $0\in E$, it follows that $B\subseteq E$.

This completes the proof of the forward direction.

For the reverse direction, assume $E$ is a subgroup of $A$ such that $A/E$ is torsion and $B\subseteq A$.

We want to show $E$ is an essential subgroup of $A$.

Let $a\in A$ with $a\ne 0$.

First suppose $a$ has infinite order.

Since $A/E$ is torsion, we must have $na\in E$ for some positive integer $n$.

Since $na$ is nonzero, we hace $E\cap \langle{a}\rangle\ne 0$.

Next suppose $a$ has finite order, $n$ say.

Since $a\ne 0$, we get $n > 1$.

If $n$ is prime, then $a\in B$, so $a\in E$, hence $E\cap \langle{a}\rangle\ne 0$.

If $n$ is composite, let $p$ be a prime factor of $n$, and let $m=n/p$.

Then $ma$ has order $p$, so $ma\in B$, hence $ma\in E$.

Since $ma$ is nonzero, we get $E\cap \langle{a}\rangle\ne 0$.

Thus $E$ has nonzero intersection with every nonzero cyclic subgroup of $A$, hence has
nonzero intersection with every nonzero subgroup of $A$.

Therefore $E$ is an essential subgroup of $A$.

This completes the proof of the reverse direction.